Probability of picking 2 A Masks and 2 B Masks From a Box of 8 total masks (3 A and 5 B Masks) over the course of 4 days
Good morning guys, i have an Exam the next week and in the List of questions in preparation for the exam the professor put this one and i have no clue how it is done.
According to the exercise Answers we must get a value of 42,86%, but he did not put how he did approach this problem, I hope someone could help me get to the answer.
"You have 3 FFP2 masks from manufacturer A and 5 from manufacturer B. Every morning, you randomly select one mask to wear throughout the day and discard it in the evening. What is the probability of wearing a total of 2 masks from manufacturer A and 2 from manufacturer B in any order over four days?"
PS: I have translated this question using chat Gpt from german to english, so if the Translation seems unclear feel free to ask or point out where the sketchy part is.

Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics from this site.  By the way, this problem is simpler to solve if you ignore the order of selection.  The favorable cases are those in which you select $2$ of the $3$ masks from manufacturer A and $2$ of the $5$ masks from manufacturer B.

Have you been taught any formula for choosing without replacement ?
